# Function which iterates through file and prints specific line

Tags: python

My code requires me to look through the game file and return each row in the file, but I am not sure if my for loop correctly does that. For example, a file might contain the data

```
 - 7D
 - AH 2D 5H 2H
 - AC 3D 4C KC
 - AS 2S 4S 3S
 - AD 4H QD 6D
 - 4D 7S 3H JD
 - 7D 5D 7C 3C
 - KS KD QS 5S
 - 7H QC QH 2C
 - JH JC KH 6C
 - 5C 6S 6H JS
```

```
def parseGameFile(fname):
    f = open(fname, 'r')
    for line in f:
        if (line[-1] == '\n'):
            data = line[:-1]
        else:
            data = line
        p_data = data.split(',')
```

and in the output, I would type `ts[0].show()`
would return the first line which contains 7D

Comment: You can use `data = line.strip('\n')` to remove the newline instead of testing and slicing.

Comment: Your file doesn't contain `,` characters between the fields, why are you using `data.split(',')`?

Comment: If it's a CSV file, use the `csv` module to parse it.

Comment: If you want to return all the lines as a list, just use `return f.read().splitlines()`

Answer (score 1):

From what I understand in your explanation, you want to return or print, all or some of the lines in a file.

Let's start by printing everything:

```
>>> with open("test.csv") as f:
...   for line in f:
...     print(line)
... 
 - 7D

 - AH 2D 5H 2H

 - AC 3D 4C KC

 - AS 2S 4S 3S

 - AD 4H QD 6D

 - 4D 7S 3H JD

 - 7D 5D 7C 3C

 - KS KD QS 5S

 - 7H QC QH 2C

 - JH JC KH 6C

 - 5C 6S 6H JS
```

Next let's say you want to return a specific line.

First we'll clean up the lines by removing the  `-` and splitting by space.

We do this by using `strip` and `split` on the resulting list.

```
>>> def parseFile():
...  with open("test.csv") as f:
...   for line in f:
...    char_list = line.strip("\n -").split(" ")
...    print(char_list)
... 
>>> parseFile()
['7D']
['AH', '2D', '5H', '2H']
['AC', '3D', '4C', 'KC']
['AS', '2S', '4S', '3S']
['AD', '4H', 'QD', '6D']
['4D', '7S', '3H', 'JD']
['7D', '5D', '7C', '3C']
['KS', 'KD', 'QS', '5S']
['7H', 'QC', 'QH', '2C']
['JH', 'JC', 'KH', '6C']
['5C', '6S', '6H', 'JS']
```

Perfect, now all we need to do is add a lookup condition.
Let's say you're looking for the **first** line that has a `"7D"` and we want the function to give it via return value:

```
>>> def parseFile():
...     with open("test.csv") as f:
...         for line in f:
...             char_list = line.strip("\n -").split(" ")
...             if "7D" in char_list:
...                 return char_list
... 
>>> list_with_7d = parseFile()
>>> list_with_7d
['7D']
```

Hope that was helpful.