# Reading Lines in file using function

Tags: python

I have tried to create a function called parseGameFile which when called can print a specific line in the file. So variable tc = line 1 and variable (ts) is the rest of the lines in the file, but I have tried to create a loop that goes through and returns all the lines. But I am not sure how to create the loop for when ts[0] or any other index it will return the second line in the file.

For example, my file contains the contents below, and if I call variable (ts) it will return '7D' and if I call ts[0] it return the line 'AH 2D 5H 2H'

7D

AH 2D 5H 2H

AC 3D 4C KC

AS 2S 4S 3S

AD 4H QD 6D

4D 7S 3H JD

7D 5D 7C 3C

KS KD QS 5S

7H QC QH 2C

JH JC KH 6C

5C 6S 6H JS

```
def parseGameFile(fname):
f = open(fname, 'r') 
contents = f.readlines()
for line in contents:
    print(line)

tc = contents[0]
return tc
for line in contents
```

Comment: I didn't understand what you are trying to achieve. Can you please show an example (input file and expected output)? Also, the indentation of the code in your post is invalid, while you're at it, you should fix that.

Comment: It would help to link to any [previous and related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74706757/function-which-iterates-through-file-and-prints-specific-line). Seems like the answer there was correctly indented and worked. What did you try to add here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using `.readlines()`, so you are almost done already.

```
def get_kth_line(fname, k):
    with open(fname) as f:
        contents = f.readlines()
        return contents[k]


k = 1  # 2nd line, due to zero-origin
print(get_kth_line("game.csv", k))
```

The piece you were missing is the `[k]` dereference
in the `return` statement.

Feel free to adjust by `+1` if you find [zero-origin](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#sequence-types-list-tuple-range)
inconvenient.
Note that requesting a line beyond EOF will
helpfully report IndexError.